# AngularJs - Persistence, storage, ajax requests, data integrity

Tags: ajax, angularjs, persistence

I'm evaluating whether AngularJS will work as a solution for my moderately simple web application.

The aim is to cut down the amount of AJAX server requests for data as much as possible.

My actual question is simple, yet the repercussions of that request is leading to confusion.

In a nutshell: "Can Angular *modify* parts of JSON data received from a backend through user input and maintain state until I'm ready to *return* that data.

Scenario:

Grab JSON data from the server that contains a root name & associated address details for each root name. The list is rendered to screen along with an 'Edit Address' button for each item.

The user clicks 'Edit Address', Angular displays a form with the address data for the root name.

The user edits the data, clicks submit, the client sends JSON data to the server and, for arguments sake, we get a success return. The address details are modified.

This is where the meat of my question - and lack of understanding - comes to the fore.

Do I need to get the *entire* list of 10 items back from the server with the single modified address details, just from editing a single list item OR can I simply *update* that single item client side and hold state as the user returns to the list, say, to edit another item?

IOW, we get a success, but no data is actually returned aside from 'success' - our client has stored the changes.

This is where the data integrity issue rears it's ugly head.

** OR **

Grab a list of root items *without* associated address data.
The user clicks on an 'Edit Address' button for the root item.
We fetch the address data for the root name from the server and the form is displayed, the user edits the data, submits, send data asynchronously, get a success. 
User returns to the list and another server request is made to grab the list from the server again.

This is hellishly difficult to explain, but the bottom line is about persistence and data integrity.

Is it best practice to make a server requests after each user *edit* of data, or can modified data be stored client side - with persistence?

*obviously* validation will be done server side, as well as client side.

Comment: Wow, I get a -2 after 4 minutes. Care to enlighten me downvoters? ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote but maybe some source code would help clarify your question even if it's pseudocode. I am trying to understand the question

Comment: Fair enough, I guess nobody has the time to read and digest the question. There's no code yet. It's a concept, the question is related to how best fetch/send data with AngularJS and maintain persistence.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is more of a server-side question, on how to design a good RESTful API that allows changes to individual entities without sending/loading the entire list each time.  So the answer to your question is that it's entirely up to you... angular does a great job of binding UI elements to the javascript objects in your controllers for you, but when it comes time to save that data to the server, you can do it however you want.

In an ideal world (IMO) your server-side API would support the following:

- Get a list of addresses (angular stores them in $scope.addresses)
- Get a single address
- PUT/PATCH to update an address (when a user makes a change to a single address and confirms it) and return 204 no content
- POST to create new addresses, and return the created address with a server-provided identifier (like "id"), that you can use in angular to determine whether an address has been persisted server-side or not.  After POSTing, you rewrite the angular scope object with what you got from the server to save the id field.
- DELETE to remove them (returning nothing)

With this, when you have the client create an address, you should send a POST to the server to create one, take the response JSON and copy it over the object you just saved, so that now it has an "id" field (or similar).  You can use angular templates to visually represent that anything with an "id" field is saved to the server.  This way you don't have to re-grab the whole list every time you save.

For updating addresses, this is why PATCH is useful: you can send only the changes to individual fields to the server and ensure that only things the user has changed get sent.

Deleting addresses can work by checking if the "id" field is there, and if so, send a DELETE to the server, and if not, the object was never "saved", so just remove the address from the scope.  Upon successful deletion you can just remove the address from the scope, no need to reload everything.

When it comes to the "data integrity", ie. if there's other addresses created since you've done the original data request, you'll have to do this on your own... Ideally similarly to how Stack Overflow or Github does it, which is to hint in the UI that there has been server-side changes and you should click to refresh.  How to determine refreshes is up to you, but you can keep it simple with polling at intervals, or you can go all out and do WebSockets/Server-side events and actually push changes to the browser.

The best way to create UIs that persist to the server is a complicated topic and there are a lot of best practices.  Angular will support whatever you want, but you need coordination on the server to do it.

Comment: Many thanks for this, Ken, a considered and damn useful reply. I had a feeling that attempting to keep persistence over an entire list *client side* was going to be a crazy idea. Now researching RESTful Java API's - thanks.

Comment: Well, you essentially are maintaining the list client-side, as an array inside your scope... but you should use individual REST calls to save items to the server as users change them.  The ng-form directive on each item, and checking the $dirty state is great for this.  Also look into angular's Resource module, which wraps a lot of the PUT/GET/DELETE/etc for you.

Comment: Ok, I get you. I understand the $scope, data binding etc. - that part is easy. The individual REST calls makes total sense - I guess there's no feasible nor logical way to do otherwise. So, effectively, AngularJS *can* update parts of a session based JSON object, rather than having to request the entire object again?